# Scan to elementbyid on button click?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

This example prompts for barcode scan, and then places the value into "scan-input" box. This works great for ONE input/ONE button.

My issue is i want to be able to add multiple inputs/buttons, and have the scan then place the value in the corresponding input text box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scandit Web SDK</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'/>

    <!-- Add the library, as explained on http://docs.scandit.com/stable/web/index.html -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scandit-sdk@4.x"></script>
</head>

<body onclick="console.log('body clicked')">
    <div id="scandit-barcode-picker"></div>
    <div id="input-container">
        <input id="scan-input" type="text" placeholder="Scan Receiver...">
        <button id="scan" onclick="scan()">SCAN
        </button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function scan() {
            startScanning();
        }
        function showScanner() {
            scannerContainer.style.opacity = "1";
            scannerContainer.style.zIndex = "1";
        }
        function hideScanner() {
            scannerContainer.style.opacity = "0";
            scannerContainer.style.zIndex = "-1";
        }
        function startScanning() {
            showScanner();
            if (picker) {
                picker.resumeScanning();
            }
        }
        function stopScanning() {
            hideScanner();
            if (picker) {
                picker.pauseScanning();
            }
        }
        // Configure the library and activate it with a license key
        const licenseKey = "LICENSE_KEY_HERE";
        // Configure the engine location, as explained on http://docs.scandit.com/stable/web/index.html
        const engineLocation = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scandit-sdk@4.x/build"
        ScanditSDK.configure(licenseKey, { engineLocation: engineLocation });
        const scannerContainer = document.getElementById("scandit-barcode-picker");
        scannerContainer.style.opacity = "0";
        scannerContainer.style.zIndex = "-1";
        const scanInput = document.getElementById("scan-input");
        let picker;
        // Create & start the picker
        ScanditSDK.BarcodePicker.create(scannerContainer)
            .then(barcodePicker => {
                picker = barcodePicker;
                // Create the settings object to be applied to the scanner
                const scanSettings = new ScanditSDK.ScanSettings({
                    enabledSymbologies: ["ean8", "ean13", "upca", "upce", "code128", "code39"]
                });
                picker.applyScanSettings(scanSettings);
                picker.on("scan", scanResult => {
                    stopScanning();
                    scanInput.value = scanResult.barcodes[0].data;
                });
                picker.on("scanError", error => alert(error.message));
                picker.resumeScanning();
            })
            .catch(alert);
    </script>
</body>
    <style>#scan:after {display:none;}</style>
</html>`
```

I want to be able to add multiple buttons/inputs. and have the corresponding button place it into the scan-input spot.

```
`<input id="scan-input" type="text" placeholder="Scan Receiver...">
<button id="scan" onclick="scan()">SCAN</button>

<input id="scan-input2" type="text" placeholder="Scan Receiver #2...">
<button id="scan2" onclick="scan()">SCAN</button>`
```

[text1] [button1] ----- scan places value into text1
[text2] [button2] ----- scan places value into text2

Comment: An easier way is to simply use a `<label>` to wrap the `<input>` element, clicking anywhere within that `<label>` will then automatically focus the relevant `<input>`; if you wish you can wrap the text of the `<label>` inside of another element and style it as, or similar to, a `<button>`. For example: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j9kL6yd3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly adapted version of your HTML (using a digit in every `id` will help us keep things simpler):

```html
<input type="text" id="scan-input1" />
<button type="button" id="scan1">SCAN</button>
<br />
<input type="text" id="scan-input2" />
<button type="button" id="scan2">SCAN</button>
```

Then, in our JavaScript, we can use the following function to send a message to `scan-input1` if `scan1` is pressed, `scan-input2` if `scan-2` is pressed, and so on:

```
[...document.getElementsByTagName('button')].forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const num = e.currentTarget.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    document.getElementById(`scan-input${num}`).value = "Scan Complete";
  });
});
```

The code above:

- Adds a click event listener to every button,
- Gets the number from the id of whichever button is clicked,
- Uses that number to target the correct input.

The advantage of the solution above is that it scales automatically. As long as you follow the same naming convention for each `id` (`scan3`, `scan-input3`, etc.), every a new button and input will have identical behaviour.

### Edit: Your Code

Below, I've inserted my suggestion into your code - only changing the bare minimum:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Scandit Web SDK</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />

  <!-- Add the library, as explained on http://docs.scandit.com/stable/web/index.html -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scandit-sdk@4.x"></script>
</head>

<body onclick="console.log('body clicked')">
  <div id="scandit-barcode-picker"></div>
  <div id="input-container">
    <input type="text" id="scan-input1" />
    <button type="button" id="scan1" placeholder="Scan Receiver...">SCAN</button>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="scan-input2" />
    <button type="button" id="scan2" placeholder="Scan Receiver...">SCAN</button>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="scan-input3" />
    <button type="button" id="scan3" placeholder="Scan Receiver...">SCAN</button>
    </button>
  </div>

  <script>
    let scanInput;

    [...document.getElementsByTagName('button')].forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const num = e.currentTarget.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
        scanInput = document.getElementById(`scan-input${num}`);
        scan();
      });
    });

    function scan() {
      startScanning();
    }

    function showScanner() {
      scannerContainer.style.opacity = "1";
      scannerContainer.style.zIndex = "1";
    }

    function hideScanner() {
      scannerContainer.style.opacity = "0";
      scannerContainer.style.zIndex = "-1";
    }

    function startScanning() {
      showScanner();
      if (picker) {
        picker.resumeScanning();
      }
    }

    function stopScanning() {
      hideScanner();
      if (picker) {
        picker.pauseScanning();
      }
    }
    // Configure the library and activate it with a license key
    const licenseKey = "LICENSE_KEY_HERE";
    // Configure the engine location, as explained on http://docs.scandit.com/stable/web/index.html
    const engineLocation = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scandit-sdk@4.x/build"
    ScanditSDK.configure(licenseKey, {
      engineLocation: engineLocation
    });
    const scannerContainer = document.getElementById("scandit-barcode-picker");
    scannerContainer.style.opacity = "0";
    scannerContainer.style.zIndex = "-1";
    let picker;
    // Create & start the picker
    ScanditSDK.BarcodePicker.create(scannerContainer)
      .then(barcodePicker => {
        picker = barcodePicker;
        // Create the settings object to be applied to the scanner
        const scanSettings = new ScanditSDK.ScanSettings({
          enabledSymbologies: ["ean8", "ean13", "upca", "upce", "code128", "code39"]
        });
        picker.applyScanSettings(scanSettings);
        picker.on("scan", scanResult => {
          stopScanning();
          scanInput.value = scanResult.barcodes[0].data;
        });
        picker.on("scanError", error => alert(error.message));
        picker.resumeScanning();
      })
      .catch(alert);

  </script>
</body>
<style>
  #scan:after {
    display: none;
  }

</style>

</html>`
```

Comment: This is exactly what im looking for. But how would i go about adding this to the already existing code? The javascript calls the getElementbyID here 

"const scanInput = document.getElementById("scan-input1");"

Would i overwrite that line using your new code?

Comment: I've edited my post so you can see a way of including my suggestion in your existing HTML.